# A word that means a bad copy of lots of other things

Tags: vocabulary

Used in this context...

I don't like The Cleveland show because it is ****

It's a term we use in animation to say that we don't like this programme or idea because it is too similar to other ones out there.

Comment: The first word that came to mind was "copypasta", but presumably not what you're looking for as it's a very recent word. Rip-off, maybe?

Comment: It's like rip-off but it's a different word, I've used it many times but I just can't remember it!

Comment: Funnily enough, when I hear that kind of example sentence, it usually ends with "mainstream", but I'm sure that's not what you were looking for.

Comment: If it was a *really* bad knock-off, I suppose you could call it a "derplicate"

Comment: For "bad copy" I'd use "Thermofax".

Answer (score 31):

Armchair pundits often like to level the accusation of a work being  [***derivative***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/derivative):

> - Imitative of the work of another artist, writer, etc., and usually disapproved of for that reason. (ODO)

But beware: that's so overdone that it, itself, has become a cliche.

Comment: @Rebe I figured. Please click the checkmark under the "0" in the top-left corner of this answer.

Comment: +1. It's kinda annoying when you don't get an accept despite cracking it, right? Edit your comment so the '0' reads '1' :)

Comment: @TusharRaj Eh, I don't hang my hat on accepts/votes here. Especially for your run-of-the-mill questions like this. Thanks for the +1 though!

Comment: @sarntheman: 'Knock-off' at the top was killing me. Had to do something!

Comment: @TusharRaj Yeah, the *order* of answers does bug/concern me more than the number of points!

Comment: @TusharRaj lol did it really bother you? Anyway +1 to Dan Bron

Comment: @samtheman: Can't say it didn't. No offense. Appreciate your sportsmanship here, though.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree here. As a native American English speaker, I would use the term knock-off. I would only use derivative if a) I wanted to sound like an art/literature/film snob or critic, b) were having a very academic/formal discussion, or c) I were discussing a legal case regarding copyright. In common, everyday usage I would absolutely say knock-off.

Answer (score 16):

I would say "knock-off"

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knockoff

You could also use "copycat"

Comment: Knock-off describes a cheaply made product, would be bizarre if applied to a TV program or idea.

Comment: @Yang Knock-off is frequently used to refer to a piece of entertainment that imitates another. For instance, the first recent example I could find easily: (http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/taken-fatigue-sean-penns-gunman-783554) accusing one film of being a knock-off of another.

Comment: I might add the variant **"cheap knock-off"** to this answer.  "knock-off" by itself does convey a lazy copy, with no real improvements, but given the desire to convey specific *negativity* from the OP, "cheap knock-off" may make it even clearer that it's likely worse than the inspiration.

Comment: I insist that this is an incorrect term for what the asker is looking for. "knock-off" implies taking short-cuts during the process in which something is made or produced, not the banality of the conception, idea or design itself.

Comment: The problem with the term knock-off or copycat is that, given the example of the Cleveland show, it was created by the same person as the show it was "copied" from.

Comment: @Roger, That's why it's called a *spin-off.*

Comment: @Mazura A spin-off is not a clone, or copy - it evolves directly out of the original. Consider _Joey_ from _Friends_, or _Better Call Saul_ from _Breaking Bad_.

Comment: I, too, would use knock-off, or possibly clone (and it is entirely possible for someone to knock-off or clone their own work - a spin-off is not *necessarily* either, but it could be). But I do note two problems. First, neither implies *bad* quality, but both do imply quality less than... The second is that both may imply a singular original as opposed to 'lots of other things.' But you could genericize a description enough to use both - for example 'of an action space opera. Also, I consider films/shows/etc. to *be* products, just not as tangible as the media they come/are stored on.

Answer (score 10):

Since you said "lots of", how about **[pastiche](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pastiche)**, instead of a simple rip-off

> 1.1 An artistic work consisting of a medley of pieces imitating various sources:

Answer (score 6):

The word ***rehashed*** may be applicable.

According to Google:

> reuse (old ideas or material) without significant change or improvement

Also, the word ***regurgitated*** may be of descriptive use.

Answer (score 2):

*Rip-off*

From [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rip-off):

> 2. music, art, films etc that are rip-offs copy something else without admitting that they are copies

Answer (score 0):

Is it [counterfeit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/counterfeit) (plural counterfeits)?

> - A **non-genuine article**; a fake.
> - One who counterfeits; a counterfeiter.
> - (obsolete) That which resembles another thing; a likeness; a portrait; a counterpart.
> - (obsolete) An impostor; a cheat.

---

mixture ?

> Something that consists of diverse elements

hotchpotch/hotchpoge ?

> A collection containing a variety of miscellaneous things.

jumble ?

> A mixture of unrelated things.

Comment: Nope, it's not a fake it's something that's a copy of a lot of different things. Not cliché either, although a very similar word.

Comment: Canned? Formulaic? Hackneyed?

Comment: Almost, honestly I've looked at the thesaurus on fake, copy, rip off, but it's a slightly more complex word than that, it means taken from a lot of things.

Comment: That sounds like "hodgepodge".

Comment: @Rebe edited to try to match what you want ^^'

Comment: @Yang Ahaha I just edited to this ;)

Comment: **eclectic** means "taken from many different sources" but it does not have anything to do with being a poor copy. Just putting it out there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it is negative enough but a '*[copycat](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/copycat)*' maybe ?

> - a person or thing that imitates another persistently or exactly.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: It's basically an amalgam of lots of ideas but not copycat, because it's not a copy of one thing, it's a lot. We use it to describe unoriginal ideas we get sent in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **plagiarism**?

It means to copy off of lots of other things.